# Is there a way to use scss mixin in jquery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I just started doing some jquery and sass so I'm a bit confused.
My question is can I use mixin like this:

```css
@mixin borderradius {
  border-top-left-radius     : 100;
  border-top-right-radius    : 100;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 100;
  border-bottom-left-radius  : 100;
}
```

in jquery code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
            borderTopRightRadius: 100,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 100
        }, 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomRightRadius: 0
        }, 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

In a way in which instead of writing all these border radius 4 times I can write something like @include borderradius or similar?
Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
           @include borderradius
        }, 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            @include borderradius
        }, 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: If all four values are the same, why not use `.animate( { borderRadius: 0 } )`?

Comment: You can! It's called a variable! Just reference the animate config object and plop them in place where you would normally write the object...

Comment: I tried using borderRadius:0 but then on mouseenter it animates very fine but on mouseleave it doest it very fast, and as I said I'm only a beginner in all this so :D!
Thanks a lot :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news!** Just use a `function` which returns the `object` you desire.

```js
function borderRadius(radius) {
  return {
    borderTopLeftRadius: radius,
    borderTopRightRadius: radius,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: radius,
    borderBottomRightRadius: radius
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate(borderRadius(100), 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate(borderRadius(0), 200);
    });
    $('#divic,#divonja').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

```css
#divonja {  background: #e1f0aa; width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divonja"></div>
```

Mmmmm, now that's some JS goodness right there. =)

Comment: Thank you a lot :D!
I just started doing some jquery and sass so it is all new for me :)!

Comment: No problem. If you feel your question has been answered, please upvote and mark this answer as accepted. Otherwise, please leave a comment.

Comment: I did mark it as accepted, unfortunately I can't upvote it since I'm new and therefore don't have 15 rep.

Comment: @i1zivkovic - Thanks anyway =)